# Unable to open Firefox browser with given URL - Selenium Webdriver & Java

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, automation, webdriver

I have written the following selenium script which opens Gmail website.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; <br>
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;

public class OpenGmail {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public void OpenGmailApp()
    {
        WebDriver webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        webdriver.get("gmail URL");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OpenGmail ob = new OpenGmail();
        ob.OpenGmailApp();
    }
}
```

When I execute the above script, I'm getting Firefox home page only. Its not gmail login page. Kindly guide what could be the error I made in that script.

Comment: Did you replace `"gmail URL"` with Gmail's actual URL, or is your code really just like what you posted?

Comment: OS of your system please ?

Comment: Hi Pavan, I have just mentioned as "Gmail URL" but in the actual code I have used the exact URL of Gmail. I'm using Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: Hi, I'm not getting any exception in the Console. Its been redirected to "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/43.0.1/firstrun/learnmore/" URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same problem. Now issue is fixed. download the latest selenium jar and replace the external jar of project in eclipse. Check the selenium jars. Selenium supports Firefox so it directly initiate the instance of Firefox WebDriver, but due to selenium jars compatibility url id not opening.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

If your jar files are old and the browser was updated to latest version, then download the latest jar files from selenium website -

[Selenium Download](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

You can also use the Selenium FF addon..

[FF Selenium Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-expert-selenium-ide/)

All the steps can be recorded in the addon and the script can be exported.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the unsigned .xpi (selenium 2.45.0) not being loaded by firefox 43. It's a temporary fix. Selenium will be going to update their jar soon after this you will not need to use this profiling

Full Code:-

```
public void OpenGmailApp()
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OpenGmail ob = new OpenGmail();
    ob.OpenGmailApp();

}
```

Another thing which can cause issue is either old selenium jars or old browser version. So update both of them.

Download latest jars from below URL:-
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi Shubham Jain, <br> Thank you for your quick reply. <br> I have updated my firefox browser version to 43.0.1 and included latest selenium jar files. But still I'm getting the same FireFox home page window when I executed the script. :(

Comment: There is nothing to do with your code. Code is fine. you can try with chrome instead of firefox. It will work.

Comment: Use lower version of firefox... 43 have an issue

Comment: The script is working fine in Chrome browser. Could you please suggest me which version is suitable for executing selenium script? Im using latest selenium JAR file i.e. selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar

Comment: Thanks Shubham Ji, Still im getting the same exception after some time i.e. closed the firefox browser. "org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:". So let me try with lower version....

Comment: oh .. Yes try with older version ... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

Answer (score 0):

If you are running via Jenkins/Command prompt then along with updating your selenium jars, delete the older version of that particular jars in your library folder. Keeping both versions might create issue while running via Jenkins/Command prompt